# Commutative local, artinian ring a homomorphic image of Noetherian (local) domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings, artinian

All rings are commutative with unity.

Is every local, Artinian ring a homomorphic image of a Noetherian *local* domain?

If this is not true, then, at least,
 Is every local, Artinian ring a homomorphic image of a Noetherian domain?

Comment: This follows from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JB and the Cohen Structure Theorem.

Comment: @Youngsu where？I don't find this.

Comment: @Sky https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/032A

Comment: Maybe the comment you want in conjunction with the Cohen structure theorem is that every Artinian ring is $I$-adically complete with respect to any ideal $I\subset A$.